# using iText v8.0 HTML to PDF converter, the row heights look ok in HTML doc but NOT OK in PDF

Tags: itext, row, height

Below is the HTML.
method being used from iText v8.0 com.itextpdf.html2pdf.HtmlConverter.convertToPdf

when rendered as a HTML, it looks fine.. when rendered as a PDF, it does NOT space out the row heights as expected.. What can I do to change this HTML (or call to convertToPdf to fix this?

Thanks in advance.

```
<html>
<head><style>
 /* Debrief Table, so want Margins at 0!!! */
 html, body {

 margin: 0;

     padding: 0;

     width: 100%;

     height: 100%;
 }
 /* Additional styles to ensure content utilizes full page */
 .full-page-content {

 width: 100%;

 height: 100%;

 /* More styles here */
 }</style><title>Reports</title>
<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8'>

</head>
<body> <table width='100%' border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' align='center'  style='font-family: sans-serif;' >         <tr>           <td align='left' style='font-size: 24px; font-family:helvetica,sans-serif'>TABLE: Results (Revenue, Process, People)</td>           <td align='right' style='font-size: 15px; font-family:helvetica,sans-serif'>Executing Strategy / Quarter 3</td>      </tr></table><br/>
<table align='center' cellspacing='0' bordercolor='#E2E2E2' style='font-size: 14px; font-family: sans-serif;' cellpadding='7'  border='1' width='100%'>
<!-- Table is: 8 col(s) wide by 7 row(s) tall -->
    <tr height="114px" style='font-family:helvetica,sans-serif'>
        <td width='27%' style='background-color:#1f497d;' align='center' valign='center'><font  style='font-size: 25.0pt' font-family='Helvetica' color='#ffffff'>&nbsp;</font></td>
        <td width='10%' style='background-color:#1f497d;' align='center' valign='center'><font  style='font-size: 25.0pt' font-family='Helvetica' color='#ffffff'>PYr Qtr 4</font></td>
        <td width='10%' style='background-color:#1f497d;' align='center' valign='center'><font  style='font-size: 25.0pt' font-family='Helvetica' color='#ffffff'>Austen</font></td>
        <td width='10%' style='background-color:#1f497d;' align='center' valign='center'><font  style='font-size: 25.0pt' font-family='Helvetica' color='#ffffff'>Burke</font></td>
        <td width='10%' style='background-color:#1f497d;' align='center' valign='center'><font  style='font-size: 25.0pt' font-family='Helvetica' color='#ffffff'>Carlyle</font></td>
        <td width='10%' style='background-color:#1f497d;' align='center' valign='center'><font  style='font-size: 25.0pt' font-family='Helvetica' color='#ffffff'>Dawson</font></td>
        <td width='10%' style='background-color:#1f497d;' align='center' valign='center'><font  style='font-size: 25.0pt' font-family='Helvetica' color='#ffffff'>Eko</font></td>
        <td width='10%' style='background-color:#1f497d;' align='center' valign='center'><font  style='font-size: 25.0pt' font-family='Helvetica' color='#ffffff'>First</font></td>
    </tr>
    <tr height="114px" style='font-family:helvetica,sans-serif'>
        <td width='27%' style='border-top: 2px solid; background-color:#1f497d;' align='left' valign='center'><font  style='font-size: 30.0pt' font-family='Helvetica' color='#ffffff'>Revenue ($MM)</font></td>
        <td width='10%' style='border-top: 2px solid; background-color:#e8ebfd;' align='center' valign='center'><font  style='font-size: 30.0pt' font-family='Helvetica'>$19.3</font></td>
        <td width='10%' style='border-top: 2px solid; background-color:#ffffff;' align='center' valign='center'><font  style='font-size: 30.0pt' font-family='Helvetica'>$21.2</font></td>
        <td width='10%' style='border-top: 2px solid; background-color:#ffffff;' align='center' valign='center'><font  style='font-size: 30.0pt' font-family='Helvetica'>$22.1</font></td>
        <td width='10%' style='border-top: 2px solid; background-color:#ffffff;' align='center' valign='center'><font  style='font-size: 30.0pt' font-family='Helvetica'>$23.0</font></td>
        <td width='10%' style='border-top: 2px solid; background-color:#ffffff;' align='center' valign='center'><font  style='font-size: 30.0pt' font-family='Helvetica'>$25.4</font></td>
        <td width='10%' style='border-top: 2px solid; background-color:#ffffff;' align='center' valign='center'><font  style='font-size: 30.0pt' font-family='Helvetica'>$24.8</font></td>
        <td width='10%' style='border-top: 2px solid; background-color:#009900;' align='center' valign='center'><font  style='font-size: 30.0pt' font-family='Helvetica' color='#ffffff'>$25.8</font></td>
    </tr>
    <tr height="114px" style='font-family:helvetica,sans-serif'>
        <td width='27%' style='border-top: 1px solid; background-color:#1f497d;' align='left' valign='center'><font  style='font-size: 30.0pt' font-family='Helvetica' color='#ffffff'>Process Complexity Index</font></td>
        <td width='10%' style='border-top: 1px solid; background-color:#e8ebfd;' align='center' valign='center'><font  style='font-size: 30.0pt' font-family='Helvetica'>155.3</font></td>
        <td width='10%' style='border-top: 1px solid; background-color:#ffffff;' align='center' valign='center'><font  style='font-size: 30.0pt' font-family='Helvetica'>131.5</font></td>
        <td width='10%' style='border-top: 1px solid; background-color:#ffffff;' align='center' valign='center'><font  style='font-size: 30.0pt' font-family='Helvetica'>154.1</font></td>
        <td width='10%' style='border-top: 1px solid; background-color:#ffffff;' align='center' valign='center'><font  style='font-size: 30.0pt' font-family='Helvetica'>153.1</font></td>
        <td width='10%' style='border-top: 1px solid; background-color:#009900;' align='center' valign='center'><font  style='font-size: 30.0pt' font-family='Helvetica' color='#ffffff'>120.5</font></td>
        <td width='10%' style='border-top: 1px solid; background-color:#ffffff;' align='center' valign='center'><font  style='font-size: 30.0pt' font-family='Helvetica'>136.3</font></td>
        <td width='10%' style='border-top: 1px solid; background-color:#ffffff;' align='center' valign='center'><font  style='font-size: 30.0pt' font-family='Helvetica'>145.3</font></td>
    </tr>
    <tr height="114px" style='font-family:helvetica,sans-serif'>
        <td width='27%' style='border-top: 1px solid; background-color:#1f497d;' align='left' valign='center'><font  style='font-size: 30.0pt' font-family='Helvetica' color='#ffffff'>Cust Care Process Capability</font></td>
        <td width='10%' style='border-top: 1px solid; background-color:#e8ebfd;' align='center' valign='center'><font  style='font-size: 30.0pt' font-family='Helvetica'>55.9%</font></td>
        <td width='10%' style='border-top: 1px solid; background-color:#ffffff;' align='center' valign='center'><font  style='font-size: 30.0pt' font-family='Helvetica'>79.1%</font></td>
        <td width='10%' style='border-top: 1px solid; background-color:#ffffff;' align='center' valign='center'><font  style='font-size: 30.0pt' font-family='Helvetica'>74.1%</font></td>
        <td width='10%' style='border-top: 1px solid; background-color:#ffffff;' align='center' valign='center'><font  style='font-size: 30.0pt' font-family='Helvetica'>71.2%</font></td>
        <td width='10%' style='border-top: 1px solid; background-color:#ffffff;' align='center' valign='center'><font  style='font-size: 30.0pt' font-family='Helvetica'>77.7%</font></td>
        <td width='10%' style='border-top: 1px solid; background-color:#009900;' align='center' valign='center'><font  style='font-size: 30.0pt' font-family='Helvetica' color='#ffffff'>79.4%</font></td>
        <td width='10%' style='border-top: 1px solid; background-color:#ffffff;' align='center' valign='center'><font  style='font-size: 30.0pt' font-family='Helvetica'>69.1%</font></td>
    </tr>
    <tr height="114px" style='font-family:helvetica,sans-serif'>
        <td width='27%' style='border-top: 1px solid; background-color:#1f497d;' align='left' valign='center'><font  style='font-size: 30.0pt' font-family='Helvetica' color='#ffffff'>BIT Process Capability</font></td>
        <td width='10%' style='border-top: 1px solid; background-color:#e8ebfd;' align='center' valign='center'><font  style='font-size: 30.0pt' font-family='Helvetica'>58.2%</font></td>
        <td width='10%' style='border-top: 1px solid; background-color:#ffffff;' align='center' valign='center'><font  style='font-size: 30.0pt' font-family='Helvetica'>77.0%</font></td>
        <td width='10%' style='border-top: 1px solid; background-color:#ffffff;' align='center' valign='center'><font  style='font-size: 30.0pt' font-family='Helvetica'>82.0%</font></td>
        <td width='10%' style='border-top: 1px solid; background-color:#009900;' align='center' valign='center'><font  style='font-size: 30.0pt' font-family='Helvetica' color='#ffffff'>82.7%</font></td>
        <td width='10%' style='border-top: 1px solid; background-color:#ffffff;' align='center' valign='center'><font  style='font-size: 30.0pt' font-family='Helvetica'>75.5%</font></td>
        <td width='10%' style='border-top: 1px solid; background-color:#ffffff;' align='center' valign='center'><font  style='font-size: 30.0pt' font-family='Helvetica'>77.6%</font></td>
        <td width='10%' style='border-top: 1px solid; background-color:#ffffff;' align='center' valign='center'><font  style='font-size: 30.0pt' font-family='Helvetica'>71.8%</font></td>
    </tr>
    <tr height="114px" style='font-family:helvetica,sans-serif'>
        <td width='27%' style='border-top: 1px solid; background-color:#1f497d;' align='left' valign='center'><font  style='font-size: 30.0pt' font-family='Helvetica' color='#ffffff'>Cust Care Employee Perf</font></td>
        <td width='10%' style='border-top: 1px solid; background-color:#e8ebfd;' align='center' valign='center'><font  style='font-size: 30.0pt' font-family='Helvetica'>62.2%</font></td>
        <td width='10%' style='border-top: 1px solid; background-color:#009900;' align='center' valign='center'><font  style='font-size: 30.0pt' font-family='Helvetica' color='#ffffff'>73.1%</font></td>
        <td width='10%' style='border-top: 1px solid; background-color:#ffffff;' align='center' valign='center'><font  style='font-size: 30.0pt' font-family='Helvetica'>70.7%</font></td>
        <td width='10%' style='border-top: 1px solid; background-color:#ffffff;' align='center' valign='center'><font  style='font-size: 30.0pt' font-family='Helvetica'>70.9%</font></td>
        <td width='10%' style='border-top: 1px solid; background-color:#ffffff;' align='center' valign='center'><font  style='font-size: 30.0pt' font-family='Helvetica'>72.5%</font></td>
        <td width='10%' style='border-top: 1px solid; background-color:#ffffff;' align='center' valign='center'><font  style='font-size: 30.0pt' font-family='Helvetica'>70.2%</font></td>
        <td width='10%' style='border-top: 1px solid; background-color:#ffffff;' align='center' valign='center'><font  style='font-size: 30.0pt' font-family='Helvetica'>72.0%</font></td>
    </tr>
    <tr height="114px" style='font-family:helvetica,sans-serif'>
        <td width='27%' style='border-top: 1px solid; background-color:#1f497d;' align='left' valign='center'><font  style='font-size: 30.0pt' font-family='Helvetica' color='#ffffff'>BIT Employee Perf</font></td>
        <td width='10%' style='border-top: 1px solid; background-color:#e8ebfd;' align='center' valign='center'><font  style='font-size: 30.0pt' font-family='Helvetica'>65.4%</font></td>
        <td width='10%' style='border-top: 1px solid; background-color:#ffffff;' align='center' valign='center'><font  style='font-size: 30.0pt' font-family='Helvetica'>71.2%</font></td>
        <td width='10%' style='border-top: 1px solid; background-color:#ffffff;' align='center' valign='center'><font  style='font-size: 30.0pt' font-family='Helvetica'>73.4%</font></td>
        <td width='10%' style='border-top: 1px solid; background-color:#ffffff;' align='center' valign='center'><font  style='font-size: 30.0pt' font-family='Helvetica'>74.1%</font></td>
        <td width='10%' style='border-top: 1px solid; background-color:#009900;' align='center' valign='center'><font  style='font-size: 30.0pt' font-family='Helvetica' color='#ffffff'>79.1%</font></td>
        <td width='10%' style='border-top: 1px solid; background-color:#ffffff;' align='center' valign='center'><font  style='font-size: 30.0pt' font-family='Helvetica'>74.5%</font></td>
        <td width='10%' style='border-top: 1px solid; background-color:#ffffff;' align='center' valign='center'><font  style='font-size: 30.0pt' font-family='Helvetica'>75.6%</font></td>
    </tr>
</table><div style="page-break-after: always;"></div>
</body></html>
```